# Use of Stored procedure

Tags: .net, sql, stored-procedures

Why would someone use stored-procedures in .net?  Also, if there is a good reason to use them, how can I?

Comment: I is kind of a "To be or not to be".
It depends what you want ro achieve. More details please.

Answer (score 3):

> The benefits of using stored
>   procedures in SQL Server rather than
>   Transact-SQL programs stored locally
>   on client computers are:
>
> **They allow modular programming.**
>
> You can create the procedure once,
>   store it in the database, and call it
>   any number of times in your program.
>   Stored procedures can be created by a
>   person who specializes in database
>   programming, and they can be modified
>   independently of the program source
>   code.
>
> **They allow faster execution.**
>
> If the operation requires a large
>   amount of Transact-SQL code or is
>   performed repetitively, stored
>   procedures can be faster than batches
>   of Transact-SQL code. They are parsed
>   and optimized when they are first
>   executed, and a compiled version of
>   the stored procedure remains in memory
>   cache for later use. This means the
>   stored procedure does not need to be
>   reparsed and reoptimized with each use
>   resulting in much faster execution
>   times.
>
> **They can reduce network traffic.**
>
> An operation requiring hundreds of
>   lines of Transact-SQL code can be
>   performed through a single statement
>   that executes the code in a procedure,
>   rather than by sending hundreds of
>   lines of code over the network.
>
> **They can be used as a security mechanism.**
>       Users can be granted permission to execute a stored procedure even if
>   they do not have permission to execute
>   the procedure's statements directly.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214299%28SQL.80%29.aspx

Comment: Stored procedures are not faster than adhoc queries. They are reparsed just like adhoc queries. Also, adhoc queries also benefit from cached query plans. Source: http://www.scarydba.com/2009/09/30/pre-compiled-stored-procedures-fact-or-myth/